# Are there any side effects of setting config.cache_store?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached, dalli

Ruby on Rails offers different caching techniques (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html)

I just want to save and fetch some data to Memcached. And I don't want to use Memcached for other types of Rails caching like page caching or SQL caching.

I added the next settings to the environment file:
`config.cache_store = :dalli_store`.
And now get worked `Rails.cache.write` and `Rails.cache.read`. That's all of I need for my task.

Can I be sure that Rails will not use :dalli_store storage for other internal mechanisms like SQL Caching.

Comment: Rails will not cache your SQL or DB output unless you explicitly tell it to. Go ahead and work with it.